# resize of usercontrols and objects inside a grid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, window

I have a WPF application, and I would like when the users resizes the window to a smaller size, for all controls to stay the same height and width but for a scroll bar to appear. I firstly set the grid row and columns, height and width to auto, but when I do this, I have all my controls go off the page. When I set a size on the row and columns, everything appears perfectly, apart from when the window reduces in size, everything gets squashed together. What is the best solution to overcome this problem? Part of my xaml code is shown below

**XAML**

```
    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="GeologicalAnalysisUI">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="255"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,2,0,2" Grid.RowSpan="6">
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,2,0,2" Grid.RowSpan="6">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="23" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="10,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="233" FontSize="11"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Geological characterisation"/><LineBreak/><Run Language="en-gb"/></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="23" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="10,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="88" FontSize="11"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Input data"/></TextBlock>
    </Border>
<Controls:SequenceTrendingControl x:Name="sequenceControlStratigraphy" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25, 12, 0, 0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sequence Stratigraphy" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="48,20,0,0" FontSize="11"/>
    <Path Data="M2.4,62 L103.4,62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="22,42,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#A8A8A8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Controls:FitButtonControl x:Name="fitButtonControlStratigraphy" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
    <Stratigraphy:StratiGraphControl x:Name="graphControlStatigraphy" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,49,5,5"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="6" />
```

**Edit**

[image]

The first picture is the one from my laptop and as you can see the controls overlap

[image]

The image above is the one that displays on my desktop

Now my question is how do I stop the overlap of things no matter what screen it is on?

Answer (score 0):

To have the `Grid` not resized when the windows size changes, you can wrap the `Grid` in a [`ScrollViewer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element. This will add scroll bars to your content instead of resizing it. Setting `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto` will display the scroll bars only when needed.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="GeologicalAnalysisUI">
        <!-- Your data -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Upscaling will still be possible unless the `ScrollViewer` is child of another control with a specific size set or e.g. a (maximum) width/height is set on the viewer itself.

Comment: I have tried to use this before, but all my controls inside go off the page and everything becomes so big, could this then be because of the user control width and height?

Comment: @RyanArchibald I actually don't really understand what you mean by everything becomes big. As far as i tried, the window i copied the code into, needs a size of 606x117 to display the content of the empty columns and rows (except for your posted content) to be displayed without scroll bars. But yes, this is definitely affected by the size of the controls (e.g. the border in column 1 row 0 with a width of 180 and a height of 23 (which is greater than the height of row 0 (20px)).

Comment: I will show to images, one of the program on my laptop and the other on my desktop and hopefully this will help explain what I mean, if it doesn't let me know and I'll try explain it better, apologies for not explaining it better initially

Comment: Added both images to try explain, with text on my problem I need to solve, any help would be great thanks.

Comment: @RyanArchibald Have you tried to set the `MinWidth`/`MinHeight` property for the columns/rows? Due to the fact that you set sizes for some items in the grid, this may causing the overlapping.

Comment: I haven't tried this for the column and rows but will give this a try, thanks for replying